Movie about Vietnam war or escaping Cambodia from Pol Pot regime
A group of children who's parents are doctors, I think and are killed by Pol Pots regime. They flee with I think its a white friend of their parents. They try to survive picking up children on the way. They're attacked by pirates and a little girl dies of tuberculosis on a boat. That's all I remember they were escaping to Australia or America I think. It may have been a TV movie. I saw it when I was about 7 in the early 90s.

Thats it thankyou!!!!!


Which Way Home (1991)
Watch the trailer. Below are snippets from reviews, matching some of the points you mentioned:

It's 1979 in Cambodia, and here we find nurse Karen Parsons ready to
  give her life to the little orphans she oversees in a makeshift
  refugee hospital. In the opening moments of the movie, a bomb destroys
  most of the hospital. Scooping up the children, Karen decides to flee
  the war-torn country for safety.

The part about picking up more kids...

Striking out for a border refugee camp, she must face Khmer Rouge
  execution squads and other dangers, plus the cultural bias of her
  young charges who object to a tagalong group of despised Vietnamese
  children.

And here's a bit about the journey...

They're finally rescued by Australian smuggler Steve Hannah, who agrees to drop them. But they have to fight off ruthless pirates, combat fatal
  disease and battle a raging storm together, before they can reach
  Darwin.

~ Edited from Entertainment Weekly, The Baltimore Sun and Amazon.com

I can't help but wonder how different this would be if it was the other John Waters.
